# Ruby require_relative path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So just to be perfecty clear.... Ruby can't handle

```
require 'filename'
```

for a file in the same directory.

*Regardless of where the script is being executed.

**But even if it is being executed from the same location.

I am reasonably new to programming but.... I must be missing something here. ***Security risk*** notwithstanding

Rails is happy with it's own load path situation so it all works nicely. 
But as soon as I want to run a script over one of these files "ruby says no".

Could someone help me please?

Thanks @pcm (too much to write in a comment)

Confidence it a low tripwire in the newb game.

Okay. Lesseons learned.

Don't fight with rails: Just allow your tests to catch any playing around with tricky refactors. Yeah.. Newbs, just wear the pain with the testing ecosystem straight off the bat.

```
require './filename'
```

will only work when the $ruby script.rb is run from the same directory as the require ./filename files. This is because, chances are one of these files is going to have to open some other file for reading/editing/preporocessing, etc. e.g.

```
File.open("./file.txt").readlines.each do |line|
```

Now, even if both files are in the same location "I think" the location of where the script is invoked will be used to open it i.e.

```
$ruby path/to/file.rb
```

and so throw a spanner.

But. If anyone could lend their experiences with this? Just so I know if I'm actually going crazy or not. I would have expected any compiler/interpreter to expect files to be in the directory/location of the file calling/using/accessing it if no filepath is specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a dot and slash before the filename to require a file in the same directory.

```
require './filename'
```

The require keyword is not aware of the current working directory, necessitating the dot and forward slash. require_relative does not have the same limitation.

Comment: Cheers! I thought that would break the Rails. Wo! What a headache..      File.open("lib/top5ImdbVids.txt").readlines.each do |line| now puts the Kybosh on what would otherwise be a trivial exercise

Comment: Glad to help! I've only been bitten by this, oh, a thousand times. :)

Comment: Ahh.. pcm     /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- ./get_top_5 (LoadError) . When executing $ruby /lib/play.rb

Comment: @JustMattfornow Can you update the question with both files and the require statements?

Comment: Cheers @pcm I think I get what is happening now. I have updated the original question